# saving subprocess output with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

my code with subprocess:

```
def GO():
    my_sub=subprocess.Popen(['exe file','files in folder'],stderr=STADOUT,stdout=PIPE)\ 
    .communicate()[0]
    my_sub=my_sub.splitlines()
    for lines in my_sub:
       GO.a= lines
       print GO.a
```

In print GO.a a have:

```
1
2
3
4
```

In save button:

```
def save():
  type = [('file', '*.txt')]
  name = filedialog.asksaveasfile(type=ftypes, mode='w', defaultextension=".xxx")


  name.write(GO.a)
  name.close()
```

In saved file i have :

```
1
```

so only 1st line, not all lines

How to save them all, or all output from `def GO()` ?

EDIT: (after comments):

```
def GO():
    my_sub=subprocess.check_output(['exe file','files in folder'],stderr=STADOUT)
    output=my_sub.splitlines()
    for lines in output:
       GO.a= lines
       print GO.a
```

In save button output i am receiving only one line (last one`4`)
`print GO.a` works well, maybe i have something bad in save button section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assigning all the lines to the same variable does that, most of the time.

`Popen` is overkill for your current needs. It's useful when you want to interact with the subprocess in a more complex way.

To just get the output+error streams merged together, use `check_output` instead, for a simpler & shorter code. This function sets `GO.a` to the output splitted lines:

```
def GO():
    output = subprocess.check_output(['exe file','files in folder'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    GO.a = output.splitlines()
```

if you're using python 3 and you need text, use

```
GO.a = output.decode().splitlines()
```

instead

Comment: hi, i have changed `my_sub=subprocess.Popen(['exe file','files in folder'],stderr=STADOUT,stdout=PIPE)\ .communicate()[0] `
to 
`my_sub=subprocess.check_output(['exe file','files in folder'],stderr=STDOUT) `
but still the same problem, could You edit my all code? maybe i dont see something

Comment: your loop is at fault. Replace all your function by mine

Comment: i did, but i cant use return in the middle of the code, at the end as well because it print me only one line ;/

Comment: in your case replace the return by `GO.a = output.splitlines()`

Comment: please take a look on my edited post, i am still receiving only one line, now its last one

Comment: use my code _as is_ for your function. Don't adapt to yours (with the loop), it's broken. Don't use a loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171230/discussion-between-sygneto-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Comment: i know what You mean, but i need to use `for line in lines` to get my output, when i am deleting this loop i dont have my result

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def GO():
    my_sub=subprocess.Popen(['exe file','files in folder'],stderr=STADOUT,stdout=PIPE)\ 
    .communicate()[0]
    lines = my_sub.splitlines()
    GO.a = my_sub
    for line in lines:
       print line
```

Comment: OP made a typo `STADOUT`

Comment: STDOUT corrected, but this mistake was only here not in my code, @boramalper your code works same as mine